# How do I make the Build modifier cyclic?

Tags: modifiers

I seem to fail to make the Build modifier cyclic because of the weird way it is constructed. The first frame is a definite value the second is a separate keyframe from the first and there seems to be no way to use 2 Build modifiers for an in and out that repeats itself.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to make it cyclic with a setup like this. No need for keyframes, just have one build modifier start up (in reverse) one frame after the first one ends:

[image: Cycle]

Obviously, view it in Object mode - I just showed it this way to show the subdivisions on my cube. I set the frame numbers for one full cycle every 250 frames.

Comment: I tried that I could not make it cyclic.